# "Iron wires" showing through sidewall

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I purchased my Suzuki Alto K10 car in 2011. In 2017, I fitted the [stepney](https://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/dic/oed/stepney/stepney.html) (AKA "spare tyre") and have driven almost 15000km.

Recently I have observed some iron wires came from side wall of this tyre, which I have taken out.

Is this tyre dangerous? Should it be replaced?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I completely agree with what motosubatsu stated in their answer. I would, however, like to state, if you only have 15kkm on the tires, you have an underlying problem with your car. You need to ensure the alignment is good and that all of the underpinnings on the vehicle are in good shape. Even the cheapest tires you can find should be lasting you longer than 15kkm. If you replace the bad tire(s) with a new one, more than likely it will just end up ruined in short order.

Comment: A picture of the tire with the visible wires sure would be helpful. Barring that, it's safest to assume it's the tire cords and bad things are happening.

Comment: You say "_...which I have taken out._".  Normally the steel belts inside a tire can't just be "taken out".  Did you run over something or is the tire so worn down in that area that the steel belts are showing?  Also, there are typically not steel wires _in the sidewall_.  I think we might have some meaning lost in translation here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this wire in my tyre?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/47903/what-is-this-wire-in-my-tyre)

Comment: I suppose OP fitted not a real tire, but a limited-use donut. 15000km's ago.

Comment: @Martin or a part-worn tyre

Comment: We delaminated a tyre on our caravan once.  I wish I'd had a camera as I've not been able to find an example image in such a "clean" state - there was literally no tread left, or any rubber for that matter, just the exposed wire.  
And we drove on it for a few miles as we didn't realise the problem O.o
Suffice it to say, I'm glad we stopped and went to put the wheel clamp on.

Comment: @Martin - it was pointed out in another comment that the original question indicated that OP was already on the spare. That detail was edited out. I'm new enough here that my edit to reinsert that is awaiting approval.

Answer (score 25):

The "wires" you mention are likely the tire cords - essentially bands of steel wire that are major structural elements of the tire's construction. If they are exposed this is an indicator of imminent failure and the tire is dangerous to be used.

If the cords are showing through the sidewall:

- **DO NOT** drive the vehicle with that tire on!
- **DO** Get the tire replaced ASAP!
- **DO NOT** attempt to "remove" the cords!

Comment: You might also note that, like Paulster noted in the comments, 150,000 km is really early to be having this problem.  The OP might consider looking for the underlying reason here.

Comment: @Cullub according to OP, it's 15,000 km which is even earlier for this type of problem. _However_, it's not that early for a _spare_ (especially if it's a compact spare), as the OP mentioned he was running. That was edited out of the OP and missed by most of us.

Comment: @Freeman - that's a very good point, I must confess I edited quite quickly yesterday and my initial research into the term "stepny" was unsuccessful so I left it out. I've voted to approve your edit restoring that information.

Answer (score 6):

Sidewall damage is almost unrepairable.  If it is indeed damage to the steel belts, the tire will fail violently (instantly) soon in the future.

That's a good reason not to be trying to change it on the car, because that involves a lot of direct handling of the tire.  **Tires can blow from handling/maintenance, and do hurt people handling them**; that's why you may see your tire shop inflate tires inside a very tough cage. *If he's afraid of a new tire, do the math..*  But it's pretty safe in your wheelwell.  **So with a structurally damaged tire, ask yourself "is this handling *necessary?*"**

Of course it's *much more dangerous* to drive the car normally at-speed and have a blowout cause a loss of control or vehice rollover.

But don't let the chicken littles fool you, **you *can* limp the car to the tire shop**. It's vital to keep speed down to a speed where you won't lose control when the tire violently fails, 20 mph (30 kph) will be absolutely fine. If you go much faster, energy in speed is a square function, so you have a wildly increasing chance of loss of control, rollover, colliding with other cars, hurting yourself *and others*, and wrecking the car of course.

Also, very important: don't just get on the main road *at any speed*. Don't let yourself into a situation wher you say "I am going fast because I *have to*", avoid those roads.  Work your way through side/back streets; a longer route is fine.  Choose roads where you will be able to stop **immediately** without disrupting traffic too badly, and once the tire is blown, you can safely handle it without fear (except of sharp edges) and  put on the spare on.  This will not be a normal soft tire, if you press onward for even 0.1mi (0.2km) you will quickly destroy the *wheel*.  Road conditions won't care; I've been in places where you had to drive another 2km to get to a safe place to change a tire, and just had to let the wheel be wrecked.  *Don't select roads like that*.

Comment: You could also use the spare...

Comment: Sure, but why change it when you don't have to...

Comment: In my local jurisdiction, a good reason to fit the spare would be to avoid prosecution and a fine.

Comment: Better would be to remove the wheels; ask a friend to transport them to the tyre shop for you, and back again when fitted with new tyres.  Once you have legal tyres on, *then* drive the vehicle to have its alignment checked.

Comment: @Harper because if there is significant sidewall damage, as everyone in every answer and comment is assuming there is, this is a time when you **have to** change the tire for safety. If you're currently driving and this type of damage happens, then yes, limp the car to a safe place to change it. If you're standing outside the car looking at the tire, **NOW** is the time to change it if there's this kind of damage. Throw the spare on it, put the damaged one in the trunk & get thineself to a tire shop pronto.

Comment: @freeman you say "throw on the spare" like a man who's changed a tire.  Most people haven't, and are intimidated by the job, and would sooner call a tow truck.  Regardless, **a damaged tire is a mini-*bomb*, and it's much better off going off inside your wheelwell for minimal/no damage, than in your hands/face while you are handling it** because that *can* hurt you.  If you don't absolutely have to, don't go near it. Editing.

Comment: @Cullub Looks like the OP has already used the spare tire, or the "[stepney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spare_tire)" (that part has been edited out of the question). I guess that the OP does not have another spare, so using the spare is out of the question.

Comment: Nice catch!  Learned a new word today ;)

Comment: @Harper valid points I hadn't considered. I still stand by my point with one caveat - deflate the tire first. Problem solved. Unfortunately, yelling **exploding tires** is not helping people overcome their DIY fear, and changing a tire _is_ simple and can save a lot of time and money. Frankly, it strikes me as "chicken little"... Like anything in life, there are simple precautions to be taken to minimize the danger. FWIW, I did upvote your answer and did so _before_ my comment or your response.

Comment: @fortunate_man excellent catch indeed! It does change the approach necessary as my comment about "putting on the spare" isn't applicable to the OP. However, I still stand by it as general advice for those who may come later.

Comment: @FreeMan well, exploding tires *is what they are*, though.  The release of forces is very violent and kills tire installers not using cages on a regular basis, and injures them *even with the cages*.  Are you familiar with all this, or is this new to you?    What euphemism would be more fititng?

Comment: Do tires tend to explode when being _deflated_?

Comment: @FreeMan yes, while being deflated, because it's on the car and you have to do something about that first (jack it or not). Either creates significant stress changes in the tire, as does the deflating itself.

Comment: Hey guys.  I think both of your points have been made -- I see both sides.  That said, I don't think we should continue this discussion here.  We're approaching the "not nice" area ;).  Have a good day!

Comment: Sorry. Not familiar with the frequency of tires exploding. I've changed lots of tires - with & w/o air in them. I know lots of people who have changed lots of tires. I've never had or heard of anyone ever having an issue. I suppose that I should never change one myself again since it's _far_ too dangerous for a non-professional to do unprotected. I will be sure to stop at the side of the road and prevent any non-professionals I see from killing themselves when changing a tire. Yes, I've seen the cages at the tire shop - my _assumption_ was that it was a necessary safety feature for [con't]

Comment: inflating the tire on the _first_ inflation where the bead may not be seated correctly and risk of explosive decompression was significantly higher. /Sarcasm. That said. I still agree with most of your advice. You're free to your opinion on the subject as well. I simply believe you've gone overboard with the scare quotes.

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate what Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said in the comment, such side-wall damage is not supposed to happen under normal conditions. You should try to discover what the problem was before fitting new tyres, otherwise you risk ruining those as well:

- check the production date of your current tyres. Were they produced in 2016/2017, or much earlier? Could be the case if you got them second-hand.
- check the camber angle. Excessive camber (which can be easily seen) may contribute to sidewall damage
- check the load index and speed rating of your tires. With a 1.2 ton car, your tires should be at least `75S`.
- check the inflation pressure. Driving with under-inflated tyres could ruin then quite quickly.

And yeah, once the steel cord breaks, the tyres are beyond repair and quite dangerous to drive on. On turn you take there's a risk that the cord will puncture the tyre, sending your car off the road.

Answer (score -3):

You can not pull the steel tire belts out; You might be able to cut them with good wire cutters.  Could you have picked up nails somewhere? I have pulled nails out of tread but never a side wall. In the tread, the heads have worn away so it becomes a "wire".